# np.where is not working correcty and need a faster way to pandas,apply

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to add a new column of true and false values in a larger dataframe depending on if the combination of the values of the other columns exited in other dataframe or array.

I initially tried this:

```
Activity = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(ActivityLog1['_created_at$AL'].unique(), _User['_p_user'].unique())),\
                     columns = ['date','_p_user'])
dft = ActivityLog1[['_created_at$AL','_p_user']].values
Activity['active'] = Activity.apply(lambda x: x[['date','_p_user']].values in dft,axis=1)
```

But it was taking so long as there are many data rows so I changed the apply function to this:

```
Activity['active'] = np.where(Activity[['date','_p_user']].values in dft, True, False)
```

I get this warning:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:6: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
```

Also all values returned are false which is not true.

```
Activity[['date','_p_user']].values
```

returns:

```
array([[Timestamp('2018-03-27 00:00:00'), 'Y5RKervPy0'],
       [Timestamp('2018-03-27 00:00:00'), 'G3zTYHC9qj'],
       [Timestamp('2018-03-27 00:00:00'), 'BeLqAK02Zo'],
       ...,
       [Timestamp('2018-09-03 00:00:00'), 'mSEZo8qHe2'],
       [Timestamp('2018-09-03 00:00:00'), 'zrERaksxxg'],
       [Timestamp('2018-09-03 00:00:00'), '7q6EuwbCgj']], dtype=object)
```

and

```
dft
```

returns:

```
array([[Timestamp('2018-03-27 00:00:00'), 'BoMRF4HvNg'],
       [Timestamp('2018-03-27 00:00:00'), 'B2QoOpL3dZ'],
       [Timestamp('2018-03-27 00:00:00'), '7G2jZJbzjT'],
       ...,
       [Timestamp('2018-08-17 00:00:00'), 'dMH2WDsbDY'],
       [Timestamp('2018-08-27 00:00:00'), 'sW13lwCQEF'],
       [Timestamp('2018-09-03 00:00:00'), 'RAJOMMfWH9']], dtype=object)
```

Any other better and/or faster way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some actual sample data so we can test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a merge, making use of the `indicator` argument:

```
Activity = Activitity.merge(dft.drop_duplicates(), indicator='active', how='left')
Activity['active'] = Activity.active.map({'both': True, 'left_only': False})
```

The `.drop_duplicates()` is to ensure the size of the left Frame remains unchanged after the merge. You can remove it (which will improve the speed) if you are certain `dft` does not contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a `isin` problem

```
Activity['active']=Activity[['date','_p_user']].apply(tuple,1).isin(dft.apply(tuple,1))
```

Comment: It is still taking a long time. I wanted a faster vectorised method